# Can you please explain the "m 1 " in the last line?

Tags: cloudera, sqoop

sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdb \
--username root \
--table emp --m 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells sqoop to use only one mapper task to perform the import operation. This will lead to creation of only 1 part file.

Answer (score 1):

It specifies the number of map tasks used to perform the import.

[source](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism)